# Recovering truncated file

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4, slackware

I'm in a peculiar situation. While editing a Perl program I accidentally truncated the file to zero length using an Emacs lisp code I was developing. I need to recover that program... how do I do that?

I tried debugfs utility, but that was of no help because the program wasn't deleted, but rather truncated to zero length & then saved by the lisp code without a prompt.

Comment: I didn't try any other utility cuz I assumed they'll work for deleted files using rm command only... Would they work ?

Comment: Roll back from the commit to your revision control system? Restore from backup?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I did it myself.

```
$ strings /dev/sda6 | grep -C 329 "print PICOTABLE" > strings.out
```